# Atom formatter that plays nicely with javascript, html and JSX

Tags: javascript, formatting, atom-editor

I have some React code in a file I'm editing with Atom.  I'm not finding a formatting package that works nicely.  For instance, I will have some JSX in a render function, and using `Beautify Language JSX` from `cmd-shift-p` will clump it all into one line.  Using another `Beautify` package leaves each element weirdly formatted, such as:

```
<
div someProp = {
   too much indentation here
}
> // why is the closing angle bracket on its own line for gods sake?
```

I've done some searching for various `APM` packages but so far haven't found a pleasant solution for basic code formatting.  I wasn't expecting this to be a such an expedition.

Is there perhaps some preferred solution to formatting React projects in Atom?

Answer (score 0):

Try babel package for atom editor.

https://atom.io/packages/language-babel

Comment: i did install that package and did not see the same behavior as shown on their site.  I'm still not understanding Atom's various constructs.  I thought this package was a "grammer" and so I would set my files language as 'language-babel' on the bottom right corner in the editor view.  But as I said, I still would get weird (or no) results when formatting.  Perhaps its because I have a plethora of competing "prettifying" packages installed battling for control?

Comment: also when i do set my language to 'language-babel-extension' syntax highlighting breaks.